# What is the connection between stipula (stalk) and stipulari (to extract a promise)?

Tags: etymology

How did the meaning of *stipulari* (to extract a promise) develop from *stipula* (a stalk), if indeed it did?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This connections is explained in *[The Etymologies of Isidore of Seville](https://books.google.com.br/books?redir_esc=y&id=3ep502syZv8C&q=stipulatio#v=snippet&q=stipulatio&f=false)* as follows:

> A stipulation is a promise or a pledge, whence stipulators are also
> called promisors. And stipulation (*stipulatio*) is so called from
> straw (*stipula*), for the ancients, when they would promise each
> other something, would break a straw that they were holding; in
> joining this straw together again they would acknowledge their pledge.

The original words of Isidore of Seville from his *[Etymologiae](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/isidore/5.shtml)*:

> *Stipulatio est promissio vel sponsio; unde et promissores stipulatores vocantur. Dicta autem stipulatio ab stipula. Veteres
> enim, quando sibi aliquid promittebant, stipulam tenentes frangebant,
> quam iterum iungentes sponsiones suas agnoscebant [sive quod stipulum
> iuxta Paulum iuridicum firmum appellaverunt].*

In his article, "[Some Latin Words and Their Ways](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3289321)", Norman DeWitt describes this sort of pledge taking place at a cattle market (based on Varro's *De Re Rustica*):

> The next step in this solemn ceremony was the guarantee or
> *stipulatio*. The vendor and purchaser faced one another holding between them the dry stalk of a plant, *stipula*, just as two people
> nowadays hold the wishbone of a fowl. The vendor then made a
> declaration such as follows: "I guarantee these animals to be of sound
> health, to be out of a healthy herd, to be without blemishes, and that
> they may be held in lawful possession." Then they broke the stalk and
> took their departure, probably to the nearest wineshop, feeling that a
> bond had been established between them. With this may be compared the
> custom of lovers who used to break a coin and carry the halves of it
> as a pledge of engagement to marry. The Roman ceremony was denoted by
> the deponent *stipulari*.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely explanation is that a stalk of wheat was used (perhaps handed over or broken in two) in an ancient ritual upon the making of certain contractual promises.